# edit PHP ini file under linux problems

Tags: php, linux, parallels

I am getting the follow when trying to create a SOAP connection in PHP

```
AutoLoader did not find file for 'SoapClient'!
```

I also checked in my phpinfo() file and i do not see anything mechining SOAP so i take it that SOAP is not installed (enabled?) on the server?

So if that is true, how would i go about installing SOAP? Is it as simple as editing the php.ini file with the following:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
extension_dir = "<full path to the 'ext' directory>"

and making sure i have php_soap.dll in the ext path?
```

But theres a problem with that as well. Its running on a linux server and we do not (or can not find an option) to edit the ini file or even get to it using Parallels.

The server is running PHP Version 5.3.3 with Apache Version 20051115

Comment: Googling `php install soap_client` should give you everything you need

Comment: Apache 20051115 is actually Apache v2.2.0. As Apache 2.4.2 is already out, you might want to consider upgrading your installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a debian derivative (like ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php-soap
```

Maybe you must restart the server after that.

Comment: But how can i do this within Parallels?

Comment: Probably you can't. Sounds like you are using a shared host? In this case you cannot do anything else then ask your hoster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, KingCrunch.

Answer (score 2):

use `sudo nano /dir/to/php/intall/php.ini` enter the password for (kinda) root user and make sure to write out the data before you exit nano.

Then restart your apache2 service through `sudo service apache2 restart` and enjoy :)

Comment: But how can i do this within Parallels?

Comment: @StealthRT If your hosting provider limits what you can do to the server, you will be constrained within the walls that they set. You can either change providers, encourage them to upgrade their servers or make do without the packages.